# BFS code using queue in c++ not working... its executing unwanted results

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
int adj_mat[1000][1000];
bool visited[1000];
int main()
{
    int v,e,x,y;
    queue<int>q;
    cout<<"enter number of vertices and edges:\n";
    cin>>v>>e;
    while(e--)
    {
        cin>>x>>y;
        adj_mat[x][y]=adj_mat[y][x]=1;
    }
    cout<<"enter the start vertex:\n";
    cin>>x;
    visited[x]=true;
    q.push(x);
    while(!q.empty()){
        x=q.front();
        q.pop();
        for( int i=1;i<=v;i++){
            if(adj_mat[x][i]!=0 && !visited[i]){
                cout<<i<<",";
                q.push(i);
                visited[i]=true;
                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code of BFS of a graph using queue in c++...But there is something wrong in this code which is creating unwanted result..
if i put input as:
vertices:4
edges:4
edges:
1
2
3
4
2
4
3
1
initial vertex 2
its showing output 1,4,3
but..its not correct...help me...

Comment: Why do you think this output is not correct?

Comment: Maybe you want to output `x` in front of the `for( int i=1;i<=v;i++)` loop instead of outputting `i` inside that loop? Otherwise I have no idea what's your problem.